# Error: `com.android.Volley.ServerError` when calling local REST service from Android

Tags: android, android-volley

I tried to call a REST service on local server from Android but I get `com.android.Volley.ServerError`.
The server works correctly when tested on Java WebFrontEnd

[image: Code in Java WebFronEnd service]

I have permission to access server using my mobile phone. And, http://ipadress:8080/myproject/rest/test works correctly on mobile phone's browser.

Code of Android function:

```
public void register ()
{
    String url ="http://ipadress:8080/FaceHub/rest/signup";
    StringRequest stringRequest =new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    })
    {

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json;charset=utf-8";
        }
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("name", "testname");
            params.put("email", "testmail");
            params.put("pass", "testpass");
            params.put("phone", "testphone");
            params.put("address", "testaddress");

            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: Please can you put full error message? 
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    System.out.println(error.getMessage());
}

Answer (score 1):

Just add `request.setShouldCache(false)` before `requestQueue.add(stringRequest);`.

By default, volley saves the response in its cache and this behavior may cause some strange problem.